extra information
How do we add extra information to this sentence?

Western tourists like to visit the ancient ruins.

and the extra information which is (are everywhere here)…
Today I had an exam and it literally made me disappointed in life  (English is not my first language so excuse me :D)
Do we need two commas or only one? This is how I wrote it

Western tourists,who are everywhere here,like to visit the ancient ruins.

Is that correct? My friends are saying it’s not correct and we only need one comma, I would appreciate it if you answer:)

You must begin every sentence with a capital letter, and there should be a space after a comma.

Any such parenthetical "extra information" must always be "set off" (delineated, surrounded by) commas / pauses. Unless it comes at the beginning or end of a sentence, in which case obviously you don't start or end the utterance with a comma.

Those are not sentences. Please punctuate correctly in the future. I have fixed them for now. And it's ancient ruins, not remains. remains are for dead bodies.

@Lambie hello thanks for answering, I’m grade 11, so it’s like a reading in our student book talk about where the tourists like to visit, here is the line (There's everything a visitor might want - from sailing on Lake to climbing in the mountains to visiting the ancient remains which are everywhere here.)

I don't know how good that book is you're using but ancient remains sounds like something you'd find in Egypt in a crypt.

@Lambie yeah it’s our student book, the reading say come to Kurdistan (I know you may didn’t hear that before) we basically have a lot of ancient remains ( like history or something if you know what I mean) I got my exam back I got 3 out of 5 I will be more careful next time, thanks again :).

Lanja, please  listen to me. People go to visit ruins in Greece, in the Middle East, in Asia, Latin America etc. They do not visit remains. remains are what you get INSIDE a tomb: old bones. Please go look up the word in a dictionary.

@Lambie,, you are right my apologies, it’s just our teacher didn't explain it properly for us, so there is a misunderstanding here , sorry for wasting your time, thanks again.

I suspect the extra information was supposed to modify "ancient ruins", not "western tourists". In that case the solution would be

Western tourists like to visit the ancient ruins, which are everywhere here.

Since the subordinate clause is at the end of the sentence only one comma is needed.

thank you so much, it’s actually ancient remains it’s a reading in our student book talk about where the tourists should visit or where they like to visit , and yeah I got my exam back and only got 3 out of 5 didn’t do pretty good but I will try next time to be more careful, and our teacher talked about that we only have one comma I just thought we had more than one because I watched a teacher on YouTube explaining it and he put two commas between the sentences so i was nervous to only add one or two, anyways thanks again:) (and excuse me again if I typed anything wrong)

Edit
The OP’s example is fine now, other than the missing spacing after the two commas.  (The other mistakes spotted by our fellow users earlier have been corrected in the edited question: the use of a small letter to start a sentence and the use of the western and remains, which should be Western and ruins.)
Bracketing commas come in  pairs unless the relative clause is at the end of the sentence.
The OP’s example will be odd if either one of the commas is deleted.  Also, we will see that the text set off by that remaining comma can no longer be deleted.  (Words set off by bracketing commas should be removable without greatly affecting the sentence.)

The initial article in OP's The western tourists, who are everywhere here, like to visit the ancient remains is extremely unlikely, UNLESS preceding text has referred to other tourists, and it's contextually necessary to specifically isolate Western tourists for this assertion. And even then, I don't think the would normally be included. But you're quite right to say that who are everywhere here is a (potentially discardable) parenthetic element that needs to be set off by commas.

...I'm not convinced you can remove either one of the commas without also removing the other. But I stand to be corrected on that, if anyone can make a case for the utterance making sense with just one comma or pause (whichever one is retained).

Thanks, @FumbleFingers.  I've edited my answer.  The commas need to stay as a pair.

I'm never too clear about acceptable punctuation for your example where the relative clause is at the end of the sentence. A comma is definitely okay, but (em-)dash, semicolon, period,... ? Whatever - I'm pretty sure no proofreader would accept  between remains and especially there.

They aren't remains, they are ruins.

Thanks, @FumbleFingers.   Yes, we need a comma between remains (or rather ruins) and especially.   That wasn't a good example and is deleted.

Thanks, @Lambie.  You're right.  It should be ruins.
